# Location always nil on WatchOS2

Tags: xcode, swift, mapkit, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to retrieve de Lat Long of my current position on my WatchOS2 app.
The app is authenticated and the iPhone app works fine.
info.plist: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` is set.

I use the following code in the `willActivate()`

```
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        if   (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse)
        {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            print("Logon: Location not authorized1")
        }

    }   

        locationManager.requestLocation()
```

In the `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` i run this code:

```
    if locationManager.location != nil
    {
        self.userLat = String(self.locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude)
        self.userLong = String(self.locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude)

        print("Lat\(userLat) Long \(userLong)")
    }
    else
    {
        print("An error occurred") <- It always prints this error
    }
}
```

```
locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
```

is not being called

Comment: Are you checking for Lat & Lng when the app is in the background on the iPhone?

Comment: @zappiDev It's a watchos2 app without a connection to the running phone app? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Ah ok, I haven't worked with the native WatchOS yet, last time I the Watch was reliant on the phone, so had to request for location service when in the background.

Comment: Do yot forget 'import CoreLocation'?

Comment: @KosukeOgawa Nope: `import CoreLocation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a library which solved my problem. I don't know what exactly happend but it works now.

I used the [OneShotLocationManger by icanzilb](https://github.com/icanzilb/OneShotLocationManager)

I've you want to use this in your WatchOS2 app, you'll have to change `startUpdatingLocation()` to `requestLocation()`, because WatchOS doesn't allow continues updates.
like so:

```
    //location authorization status changed
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    switch status {
    case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        self.locationManager!.requestLocation()
    case .Denied:
        _didComplete(nil, error: NSError(domain: self.classForCoder.description(),
            code: OneShotLocationManagerErrors.AuthorizationDenied.rawValue,
            userInfo: nil))
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Give Credit Where Credit Is Due -

Comment: Please mark this question as answered, as you've supplied the answer.